# java version conflict on windows

Tags: java

I usually work with java 11 on my computer but then I installed java 8 to run both.

Now when I run java -version, it shows java 8. I find it odd because my environment variables point towards 11. In addition javac -version shows 11. Seems it's not clear to my system which one is the  current version.

I try many solution I found here but nothing seems to work, unless I uninstall java 8.

How can I resolve this and cleanly switch between both (or many) java version on my pc ?

Comment: @Abra makes the crucial point about PATH order. I work in the terminal so it's trivial to write scripts like `j8` and `j16` to set JAVA_HOME to the necessary value. All you need in PATH is `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`

Answer (score 2):

The operating system on your computer uses the PATH environment variable to locate the `javac` executable. Hence the `bin` subdirectory of your JDK 11 installation appears in the value of the PATH environment variable. Note that the `bin` subdirectory of your JDK 8 installation may also appear in the value of PATH but since you say that `javac -version` shows 11, that means that if both JDK 11 `bin` and JDK 8 `bin` are on the PATH then JDK 11 appears *before* JDK 8. That's why, when you issue `javac -version` it shows 11.

Regarding the output of command `java -version` that depends on other details which I could not find in your question, including (but not only) which JDK 8 you installed. If it is Oracle's and if you installed JDK 8 *after* you installed JDK 11, that would explain why `java -version` shows 8.

Note that if you want to run a specific JDK, you can always enter the full path to the file `java.exe` when you enter the command - rather than just `java`.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I installed java 11 before 8. I honestly don't remember if it's Oracle's because I dowloaded it a long time ago, just didn't installed it. What difference does it make ? It says java 8 update 202.
Only java 11 is in PATH.

Answer (score -1):

On windows 10, you have to change both `JAVA_HOME` and `Path`.

1. Change `JAVA_HOME` to point towards your desired version.
2. In `Path` make sure the desired version comes **before** the other one.

This works for me(i switch frequently between java 8 and 11).